# Windows service taking up 99% of cpu usage

Tags: c#

I created a windows service but it is eating up 99 % or the cpu usage, is there something I should be calling in c# code once what needs to be done is done?

Like is there some sort of "idle" state so the service is still listening on a port but isn't eating up so much cpu usage?

edit

```
    if (store_number.ToString().Length >= 3)
    {

        store_no_Folder = store_number.ToString();
        try
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder))
            {
                logInfor.log("Creating: " + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder + archived);
                try
                {
                    addst.aaddStation(ecm_path + "\\stations.xml", store_no_Folder, ecm_path);
                }
                catch (Exception ss)
                {
                    logInfor.log(ss.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ds)
        {
            logInfor.log(ds.ToString());
        }
        if (!Directory.Exists(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder + archived))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder + archived);
        }
        try
        {
            doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder + archived + "\\" + dateTime + "_SO.xml");
            doc.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder + "\\" + dateTime + "SO.xml");
            logInfor.log("Saving SO.xml to designated folder: " + stored_xmls);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder);
            for (int v = 0; v < files.Count(); v++)
            {
                /*fileN = files[v];*/

                while (files[v].Contains("\\"))
                {
                    files[v] = (files[v].Substring(files[v].IndexOf('\\') + 1));
                }
                logInfor.log("Moving :" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder + "\\" + files[v] + " ---> " + ecm_path + "\\Polling\\001" + store_no_Folder + "A\\OUT\\" + files[v]);
                addst.moveFiles(files[v], AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder, ecm_path + "\\Polling\\001" + store_no_Folder + "A\\OUT\\");
            }


            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + locations + store_no_Folder);
            FileInfo[] Ffiles = di.GetFiles("*.xml")
                        .Where(p => p.Extension == ".xml").ToArray();
            foreach (FileInfo file in Ffiles)
                try
                {
                    logInfor.log("Deleting: " + file.ToString());
                    file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
                    File.Delete(file.FullName);
                }
                catch { }
            response = "Success";
        }
        catch (Exception arg)
        {
            response = "Failed";
            logInfor.log(arg.ToString());
        }

        logInfor.log("MESSAGE TO CLIENT CALLING METHOD: " + response);
        return response;
    }
    else
    {
        logInfor.log("Store number is out of range");
        response = "Store numbers have exceeded 999";
        return response;
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    response = "Failed";
    logInfor.log(err.ToString());
    logInfor.log("MESSAGE TO CLIENT CALLING METHOD: " + response);
    return response;
```

I added the code.

Comment: Show your code. We can't help you without it; a service will never eat up 99% cpu unless it does use the cpu.

Comment: Post your code - sounds like you have a runaway loop somewhere

Comment: proof of the service eating up 99% of the CPU would probably be nice too.

Comment: This isn't related to the problem, but please look into the `Path` class in MSDN.  There are helper methods to form paths, retrieve filenames, etc.

Comment: @Tyress I can upload a picture i suppose but after I call the web service I open the task manager up and I see it jump from 0 to 25% and then run it again and it goes up to 50% call it enough times and it goes up to 99%

Comment: Please format the code on your own next time. People here tend to put the same effort into answering a question that you do into asking. Poorly formatted code shows not much effort went into asking. Also, this isn't _all_ the code... some is clearly missing because the braces don't match up. Finally, this is still _too much code_. There's a lot in here that has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @JOelCoehoorn understood, sorry I thought the error was with this portion but frustration made me go through it from the top and noticed the error but will put more time into asking the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem it was with a different part of the code this was okay but it was basically an exception I didn't catch fixed it and now it works fine.

Thanks everyone for helping